# Swift UIAlert - get data from dataTaskWithRequest

Tags: swift, uialertview, uialertcontroller

i need the variable 'response' to be taken from "dataTaskWithRequest". Right now, 'response' is not found because it is outside of the brackets. How can i make sure to pass the response variable to the UIAlert? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func buttonCreateAccount(sender: AnyObject) {
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/createaccount.php")!)
            request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
            let postString = "user_name=\(username.text!)&email=\(email.text!)&password=\(password.text!)"
            request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil {
                    print("error=\(error)")
                    return
                }

                print("response = \(response)")

                let response = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                print("responseString = \(response)")

            }

            task.resume()

//problem is here. 'response' variable cannot be taken from above. i need it to be taken from above.
            if response == "Username taken" {
                if let getModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") { // iOS 8
                    let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Registration", message: response, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else { // iOS 7
                    let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alert.delegate = self

                    alert.title = "Registration"
                    alert.message = "Testing"
                    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")

                    alert.show()
                }
            } else {
                if let getModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") { // iOS 8
                    let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Registration", message: response, preferredStyle: .Alert)
                    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
                    self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else { // iOS 7
                    let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
                    alert.delegate = self

                    alert.title = "Registration"
                    alert.message = "Testing"
                    alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")

                    alert.show()
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: The completion block (the code you have specified immediately below `NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request)` is going to get executed asynchronously - it won't be executed until the request actually completes, which will probably be several milliseconds to several seconds after this function is called. The code beneath your comment will be executed **immediately**, at which point you won't have a `response` to work with.

You need to move all of the response processing code into the completion block as well. That way it won't get executed until the response is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dataTaskWithRequest` runs **asynchronously**. You will not get the response immediately. Separate it into two functions:

```
@IBAction func buttonCreateAccount(sender: AnyObject) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/createaccount.php")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "user_name=\(username.text!)&email=\(email.text!)&password=\(password.text!)"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let response = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(response)")

        // Now that the response is ready, call the other function to handle it
        handleResponse(response)
    }

    task.resume()
}

func handleResponse(response: String) {
    if response == "Username taken" {
        if let getModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") { // iOS 8
            let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Registration", message: response, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else { // iOS 7
            let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alert.delegate = self

            alert.title = "Registration"
            alert.message = "Testing"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")

            alert.show()
        }
    } else {
        if let getModernAlert: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UIAlertController") { // iOS 8
            let myAlert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Registration", message: response, preferredStyle: .Alert)
            myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else { // iOS 7
            let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
            alert.delegate = self

            alert.title = "Registration"
            alert.message = "Testing"
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")

            alert.show()
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this: "Cannot convert value of type 'NSURLResponse' to expected argument type 'String?'"

Comment: Ah... I didn't see that response is a string. Change the function's argument to: `func handleResponse(response: String)`

Comment: Thanks. I get this now: "Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?"

Comment: Yes, you should call `handleResponse(response!)`

Comment: Okay, it works now but here is an error I get: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

Comment: I'm trying to put an alert dialog in the handleResponse function but it gives me errors. any ideas?